# Facter: Custom-fact-script "was parsed but returned an empty data set"

Tags: puppet, facter

For facter/puppet, I installed a one-line shell script. Several, actually. On subsequent runs, and with `facter -p`, I see the following output:

```
Fact file /etc/facter/facts.d/system_facts_<factname>.sh was parsed but returned an empty data set
```

If I run the script manually from the command-line, I get the expected output. If I use `facter -p <factname>` I get the empty string.

Puppet version: 3.8.2

Note: not a duplicate of [Facter - custom fact, returns empty data set when invoked by Puppet agent](https://serverfault.com/questions/601717/facter-custom-fact-returns-empty-data-set-when-invoked-by-puppet-agent)

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation helped me realize the script must produce output in the form of `key=value`. Thus, a single script can generate many different sets of information. (Now I realize why facter is so damn slow.) But if it produces output in just the form of `value`, facter doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: Yes, but how does this relate to Facter's performance? Just being curious about your reasoning here.

Comment: Because it cannot assume that file X is associated with fact Z, it must search through all possible facter files before it can report on any of them. The end-result is a _a lot_ of file touches. My strace indicated it was opening each possible fact file _3 times_. I also see how facter may have architecturally built in sluggishness to their design -- by allowing facts to be declared multiple times, each with different "weights", it might be impossible to cache the data.